# I am trying to store data which I received from serial port to a variable using popen

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, popen

I am building serial communication system with C++ and I am facing a challenge right now. Originally I used system(cat /dev/ttyUSB0") and I could see the printed result at the terminal. However, when I changed my code into popen, It keep shows error. I got following error message.

```
receiver.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
receiver.cpp:9:34: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
   fp=popen("cat /dev/ttyUSB0",'r');
                                  ^
In file included from receiver.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:874:14: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘FILE* popen(const char*, const char*)’
 extern FILE *popen (const char *__command, const char *__modes) __wur;
```

Following is the c++ script which I made. (Although I am using C libraries right now,I am compiling this as cpp for future usage.) Could anyone tell me what is the problem and offer me clear solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char var[100];
  //system("stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb &&");
  FILE *fp;
  fp=popen("cat /dev/ttyUSB0",'r');
  while(true)
    {
      fgets(var,sizeof(var),fp);
      printf("%s",var);
    }
  pclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second argument to `popen` must be a string, not a character.

Comment: Change: `'r'` -> `"r"`

Comment: Using `popen` with `cat` is a rather roundabout way of doing this, and I doubt it will work well.  Why don't you do `fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0", "r")`?